# the degree of the multiplier of Misiurewicz points

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Define the iterated complex quadratic polynomial
$$\begin{aligned}f^{0\phantom{+1}}_c(z) &= z \\ f_c^{n + 1}(z) &= (f_c^n(z))^2+c\end{aligned}$$

A Misiurewicz point $M_{q,p}$ satisfies
$$f_c^{q + p}(0) = f_c^q(0)$$
where $q > 0$ is the preperiod and $p > 0$ is the period.  The equation also has roots with lower preperiod (including $0$) and/or period, these should be discounted.  By construction each $M_{q,p}$ is an algebraic integer.  The multiplier $m$ of $c = M_{q,p}$ is defined as
$$ m = \prod_{n = q}^{q + p - 1} 2 f_c^n(0) $$
and is also an algebraic integer.

**Question: is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $m$ always equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $M_{q,p}$?**

(I had previously tabulated an attempt at finding the polynomials, but I realize now that I didn't check for irreducibility properly, so I removed the misleading tables and code from here and put them on my [blog](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2018-08-06_enumeration_of_misiurewicz_points.html) instead.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740655/golden-spirals-in-the-mandelbrot-set related

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875056/counting-misiurewicz-points related