# counting Misiurewicz points

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, complex-dynamics

I [enumerated](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2018-08-06_enumeration_of_misiurewicz_points.html#mqptable) the number of [Misiurewicz points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misiurewicz_point) using [SageMath](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2018-08-06_enumeration_of_misiurewicz_points.html#mqpsage) to factor into irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$, where the degree (after discarding factors corresponding to lower (pre)periods) gives the number of roots over $\mathbb{C}$ (which are guaranteed to have multiplicity $1$).  Then I played around trying to fit a function to the data in [Haskell](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2018-08-06_enumeration_of_misiurewicz_points.html#mqphaskell), and came up with this $M(q,p)$ that counts the number of Misiurewicz points in the Mandelbrot set:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H :\mathbb{N^+} &\to \mathbb{N} \\
H (p) &= \sum_{d \mid p} \mu\left(\frac{p}{d}\right) 2 ^ {d - 1} \\
M :\mathbb{N^+} \times \mathbb{N^+} &\to \mathbb{N} \\
M (q, p) &= \left(2 ^ {q - 1} - \mathbf{1}_{q \equiv 1 \mod p}\right) H (p)
\end{aligned}
$$

$\mu$ is the [Moebius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).
$\mathbf{1}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition).  H(p) counts [hyperbolic components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Hyperbolic_components) with preperiod $0$.
$q$ is the desired preperiod, $p$ is the desired period.

**However** while this fits all the data I have available ($q + p \le 16$), and I know that [$H$ is correct](https://oeis.org/A000740), I have no proof of correctness of $M$.  Any ideas how to go about proving this?  In all my tests I ended up with just $1$ irreducible polynomial, with multiplicity $1$, after discarding lower (per)period factors.  But tests are not a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Misiurewicz Points for Polynomial Maps and Transversality by Benjamin Hutz, Adam Towsley](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4048v2)

> **Corollary 3.3.** The number of $(m,n)$ Misiurewicz points for $f_{d,c}$ is
>   $$
> M_{m,n} = \begin{cases}
> \sum_{k \mid n} \mu\left(n \over k \right) d^{k-1} & m = 0 \\
> (d^m - d^{m-1} - d + 1)
> \sum_{k \mid n} \mu\left(n \over k \right) d^{k-1} & m \ne 0 \text{ and } n \mid (m - 1) \\
> (d^m - d^{m-1})
> \sum_{k \mid n} \mu\left(n \over k \right) d^{k-1} & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

There is a typo in the PDF statement of the corollary ($k \mid d$ in place of $k \mid n$), but its proof uses $k \mid n$, so the above is not a verbatim quote.

They have $f_{d,c}(z) = z^d + c$, so this result is more general than the case $d = 2$ I asked about.